# Looping through DOM to modify elements

Tags: php, dom

I'm using this PHP to modify A elements in a DOM fragment (a vBulletin `$post['message']` if that matters) so that links to external sites always open new tabs. This is actually the default in vBulletin but it's not always reliable. Anyway, the code works, but looking at the loop makes me think it could be done better. Any suggestions?

```
$as = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
for ( $i = $as->length; --$i >= 0; ) {
    $a = $as->item($i);
    $aParts = parse_url ( strtolower ( $a->getAttribute('href') ) );
    if ( $aParts['host'] !== $localDomain ) {
        $a->setAttribute ( 'title', @$a->getAttribute ('title') . " [external link to {$aParts['host']}]" );
        $a->setAttribute ( 'target', '_blank' );
    }   // if
} // for
```

Comment: interesting that you inverted the loop and counted down from `NodeList::length` - did you have a particular reason for doing it that way?

Comment: @prodigitalson I adapted that from another area where I'd removed an element during the loop; if you count from the beginning, the index gets messed up when you remove one, but if you count from the end it works. No particular reason for doing it that way this time, just some consistency.

Comment: Looks OK to me. Not sure how it would perform with a high number of iterations. It might be overkill, but another approach would be to run  some XSL on this DOM, using an identity/copy pattern to output the same HTML, but with the tweaks you require.

Comment: @AndrewRich You know you can just `foreach` over a `DOMNodeList`, right?

Comment: @Utkanos There aren't usually a large number of links in each message (so not many iterations each time), but the code is called as many times as there are posts on a thread page, which could be as many as 50.

Comment: @DaveRandom I didn't. Can you give me or point me to an example? Thanks.

Comment: You literally just treat it the same way as you would an array. Like you could do [this](http://codepad.org/6mOXZ5AN).

Comment: I might get flamed for this, but I'd probably REGEX it. Generally you should favour DOM methods over REGEX for this sort of thing, but REGEX wins on performance in cases where there's potentially a large loop.

Comment: If you look at the docs you'll see that [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) implements the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) interface - which means it will behave just like an array when used with `foreach`

Comment: @Utkanos Careful now... You're in danger of getting flogged for heresy or burned as a witch...

Comment: @DaveRandom Thanks, that's much appreciated.

Comment: @DaveRandom - haha, good job us REGEX sadists are not easily inflamed...

Answer (score 2):

To make it elegant clean code I would:

- make proper use of blank lines;
- abide by the coding standards defined by [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/);
- use the `DOMNodeList` object as an array so I can use `foreach()`;
- be consistent with either single `'` or double quotes `"`;
- use a [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause).

**Refactored code:**

```
$aEls = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($aEls as $a) {
    $url = parse_url(strtolower($a->getAttribute('href')));

    if ($url['host'] === $localDomain) {
        continue;
    }

    $title = $a->getAttribute('title') . ' [external link to ' . $url['host'] . ']';

    $a->setAttribute('title', $title);
    $a->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
```

(*not tested*)

Answer (score 1):

DOM is a tree structure that consists of well defined objects (nodes) therefore I wouldn't use *for* loop.
Moreover, I don't know how *for* would influence the code if you need to do more radical actions like delete an element. I know for sure that if you delete an element while you are in a *foreach* loop you get an error and your changes are not committed.

There are 2 other easy ways to find elements in the DOM without using *for* or *foreach*:
- use Xpath - I would say the common and easiest approach because it doesn't need difficult coding
- use a recursive function to go through DOM; below how I would code this using an abstract class and closures. Another option is just to use a standard function in the global context but closures give some flexibility.

```
abstract class Utils
{
    static function loop(&$elem,$func)
    {
        $closure = function(&$el,$func){
            if($el->nodeType == 1 && $el->nodeName == "a"){
                $func = $fun->bindTo($el);
                $func($el);
                }
            else {
                if($el instanceof DOMNode && $el->hasChildNodes()){
                    $current = $el->firstChild;
                    while($current instanceof DOMNode){
                        self::loop($current,$func);
                        $current = $current->nextSibling;
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
        return $closure($elem,$func);
     }
}

Utils::loop($documentRootNode,function(&$a){
//do what you have to do here
//your A is either $a parameter or $this
//binding is not necessarily needed but is an option
});
```